# configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, makefile, config

I'm trying to install different software onto my Raspberry Pi with Debian Wheezy OS. When I run try to configure software I'm trying to install I get this output

```
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling...  configure: error: in 'directory of where I'm installing the software'
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.
See config.log' for more details
```

So then I check the config log and it basically says the same thing, the only difference is I see there was a segfault when checking whether cross compiling:

```
configure:3547: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3554: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest -Wno-long-long    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3558: $? = 0
configure:3580: result: 
configure:3602: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3610: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest -Wno-long-long    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3614: $? = 0
configure:3621: ./conftest
./configure: line 3623:  3679 Segmentation fault    ./conftest$ac_cv_exeext
configure:3625: $? = 139
configure:3632: error: in `/usr/local/src/VALGRIND/valgrind-3.10.1':
configure:3634: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

This error has come up twice now. Once when trying to install Valgrind and once when trying to install libusb.

The output with gcc -v is this:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-   languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
```

Comment: *Are* you cross compiling?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm just trying to configure make and install this software for linux

Comment: Are you running all of the above on the RPi itself?

Comment: The errors suggest that `/usr/bin/gcc` is a compiler which outputs executables for another architecture than the computer it is running on.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am running all the above on the RPi

Comment: @nemetroid are you suggesting I should install a new c Compiler then??

Comment: How this one was installed? Can you run it? What `gcc -v` is telling us?

Comment: @EugeneSh. wget http://www.valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.10.1.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf valgrind-3.10.1.tar.bz2
sudo ./configure

Comment: literally the directory where I install it. In this case /home/VALGRIND @EugeneSh.

Comment: The compiler should be fine.. Can you compile and run a simple `c` program?

Comment: let me try real quick @EugeneSh.

Comment: yea it runs and compiles @EugeneSh.

Comment: Interesting. There is some code in `conftest.c` that is segfaulting.

Comment: it did segfault before, but then I ran it with sudo and it worked

Comment: possibly the issue @EugeneSh. ?

Comment: You can run it with sudo, actually.. no harm with that as it will only update the makefiles. But it might be beneficial to understand the root of the problem. Try examining the conftest.c and determine the point it is crashing.

Comment: I ran it with sudo ./configure before and that's where the issue arose. But you've narrowed down the issue. I'll let you know what I find in the conftest.c @EugeneSh.

Comment: its probably problem if sudo find / -name 'conftest.c' doens't come back with an directory isn't it? @EugeneSh.

Comment: duh.. it is generated dynamically by the script.. Check the config log, it should have it's contents.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here has been resolved by:

```
export PATH=/path/to/gcc-4.9.2/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gcc-4.9.2/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./configure --prefix=/path/to/  --host=arm
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

On CoreOS, solved the problem with.

```
install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args='--host=host')
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error. When I looked in `config.log` I saw the message:

`fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory`

To fix this, I ran:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`

I could then configure and compile my program.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason was that the version of libasan did not match the version of gcc. Just update the version of libasan.aarch64 to be the same as the gcc version.

```
[root@node1 isa-l]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="openEuler"
VERSION="22.03 (LTS-SP1)"
ID="openEuler"
VERSION_ID="22.03"
PRETTY_NAME="openEuler 22.03 (LTS-SP1)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"

platform: Kunpeng-920

[root@node1 isa-l]# yum list installed |grep gcc
gcc.aarch64                                                                10.3.1-20                          @OS
gcc-11.2.0-runtimes-Generic-AArch64-RHEL-8-aarch64-linux.aarch64           11.2.0-193                         @System
gcc-c++.aarch64                                                            10.3.1-20                          @OS
gcc-gdb-plugin.aarch64                                                     10.3.1-20                          @OS
gcc-gfortran.aarch64                                                       10.3.1-20                          @OS
libgcc.aarch64                                                             10.3.1-20                          @OS
[root@node1 isa-l]# yum list installed |grep asan
libasan.aarch64                                                            10.3.1-20                          @everything
```