Cannot build gnu scientific library for x86_64 architecture
I am on macOS 14.6 and I want to build Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) for x86_64 architecture.
I have an Xcode app which uses GSL, but when I compile this app I get the warning message 'ld: warning: ignoring file '/usr/local/lib/libgsl.28.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
and none of the GSL module is found (they are all properly linked).
How may I build GSL for x86_64? The suggestion in the INSTALL file to do
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch x86_64" CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"

does not work, it yields the error message
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch x86_64" CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin23.6.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin23.6.0
checking for gcc... gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in '/Applications/gsl-2.8':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.
See 'config.log' for more details

I also tried to add --host and it does not work
./configure --host CC="gcc -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch x86_64" CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for CC=gcc... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin23.6.0
checking host system type... config.sub: too many arguments
Try `config.sub --help' for more information.
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub CC=gcc -arch x86_64 failed

Any ideas ? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943461/configure-error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs

-arch i386 is definitely not going to work on modern macOS; they only support 64-bit mode.  But it looks like you did also try with just -arch x86_64.  (Which isn't a standard GCC option; normally it's -m64, which will be the default for x86-64 GCC on macOS.)

@petercordes ... so ? $ ./configure CC="gcc -arch m64" CXX="g++ -arch m64" CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E" yields the same error configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

Not -arch -m64, just -m64.  -arch isn't a GCC option.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html

@petercordes with -m64, ./configure runs correctly, thank you, and so do make and make install. However, when I build my app, I still have the error ld: warning: ignoring file '/usr/local/lib/libgsl.28.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64' .  I verified that /usr/local/lib/libgsl.28.dylib is the one that I just installed with your command.

Do you have x86-64 GCC installed?  -m64 won't switch it from AArch64 to x86-64; there's no option that can do that.  A single build of GCC can only target one ISA (unlike Clang).  You probably need to install a cross-compiler like x86-64-apple-darwin-gcc or something; I don't know the exact name to search for.  I was assuming that's what your gcc command was, but if it build an AArch64 library then it isn't.

I don't know how to tell if I have x86-64 GCC installed . How may I check that ?
